# Problema al ingresar 2 strings contiguos con cin.get(cadena,dimension,'\n')

Tags: c++

tengo un problema al ingresar 2 cadenas de caracteres, una después de otra, y es que luego de ingresar con el cin.get(cadena,dimension,'\n') la cadena **A** es necesario presionar 2 veces `enter` para que me permita ingresar la cadena **B** (lo mismo ocurre luego de ingresar B).
Analizando, me di cuenta que el `cin.ignore(256,'\n')` es el responsable de esto, sin embargo es necesario, así que consulto ¿qué puedo hacer para solucionar esto?. Aquí está el código, el cual se encarga de combinar los arreglos **A** y **B** en uno **C**:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

//PROTOTIPOS

char* combinar(char*,char*);

int main(int argc,char *argv[]){

    int N=0;

    char *A,*B,*C;

    cout<<"Ingrese dimension de A y B: ";

    cin>>N;

    while(N<=0){

        cout<<"Error, ingrese una dimension valida: ";

        cin>>N;

        cout<<endl;

    }

    cin.get();

    A=new char[N];

    B=new char[N];

    cout<<"Ingrese cadena A: ";

    cin.getline(A,N,'\n');

    cin.clear();

    cin.ignore(256,'\n');

    cin.get();

    cout<<"Ingrese cadena B: ";

    cin.getline(B,N,'\n');

    cin.clear();

    cin.ignore(256,'\n');

    cout<<endl;

    C=combinar(A,B);

    cout<<endl;

    cout<<"A y B combinadas: "<<C<<endl;

    cout<<"Longitud A y B combinadas: "<<strlen(C)<<endl;

//ELIMINO ESPACIO EN MEMORIA

    delete[] A;

    delete[] B;

    delete[] C;

//  system("pause");

    return 0;

}

char* combinar(char *a,char *b){

    char *c;

    int n=0,k=0;

    bool bandera=true;

    while(*(a+k)!='\000'){

        k++;

    }

    n=k+1;

    int j=0,i=0,t=-1;

    c=new char[n];

    for(i=0;i<2*n;i++){

        if(bandera==true){

            *(c+i)=*(a+i);

            j++;

            if(*(c+i)=='\000'){

                bandera=false;

                i--;

                j--;

            }

        }else{

            *(c+i)=*(b+i-j);

            cout<<"["<<i-j<<"] = "<<*(c+i)<<endl;

        }

        cout<<*(c+i)<<endl;

    }

    *(c+i)='\000';

    return c;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

> es necesario presionar 2 veces enter para que me permita ingresar la cadena B

Eso pasa porque tienes un `get` que no debería estar ahí

```
cout<<"Ingrese cadena A: ";

cin.getline(A,N,'\n');

cin.clear();

cin.ignore(256,'\n');

cin.get(); // <<--- AQUI!!!

cout<<"Ingrese cadena B: ";

cin.getline(B,N,'\n');
```

Esa instrucción lee un caracter de la entrada estándar, y da la casualidad de que en C++, las lecturas son bloqueantes, lo que te fuerza a introducir un salto de línea para avanzar.